# How to interpret recommender scores in implicit matrix factorization?

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system

I am using Alternating Least Squares model from the [Implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit) library on the LastFM dataset, recommending artists to various users.

The input data is simply a sparse matrix of users, artists, number of listens.

I'm having a difficult time interpreting the list of recommended artists and scores.

A lot of the scores seem to hover around 1.1, for example, I below is a recommendation for `user_id 1234`:

```
model_als.recommend(1234, user_item_matrix)    

                             artist     score
0                               npr  1.204484
1                      brian wilson  1.190483
2          neil young & crazy horse  1.147750
3            sly & the family stone  1.141859
4                     the beta band  1.132374
5                          the band  1.128185
6  elvis costello & the attractions  1.118344
7                       david byrne  1.114423
8                    charlie parker  1.105284
9                 mark mothersbaugh  1.103784
```

Are these good scores? Can I be confident in these recommendations? And what's the scale/range of the score? Is it out of 100? What is the lowest/worst possible score?

I've googled everywhere and can't find a definitive answer, even on the library's github page.

I've also calculated similar users to another user, and the scores go up to the 40s. Which confused me even more. (See below). Anybody know how to interpret this?

Getting similar users to `user_id 1234`. How similar are they? Does the high score mean they are not similar?

```
model_als.similar_users(1234)

   users similar to 178141      score
0                   336798  43.835110
1                   205426  41.776321
2                   104129  41.578308
3                   328411  41.425632
4                   113997  41.309204
5                   229685  41.287209
6                   147693  41.177387
7                    34985  41.175827
8                   264109  41.130024
9                   306444  41.095680
```

I also checked for artists similar to Metallica, and got these results. The list of artists makes sense, but the score is now closer to zero:

```
  artist similar to Metallica     score
0                   metallica  0.043550
1            system of a down  0.043278
2               guns n' roses  0.043231
3                   rammstein  0.043230
4                       ac/dc  0.043155
5                guns n roses  0.043151
6                 iron maiden  0.043147
7                 tenacious d  0.043136
8                        koЯn  0.043067
9               the offspring  0.043035
```

Is a score close to zero is the best possible score? It must be, because metallica is literally equal to metallica, and it scored `0.043550`. Which makes me think that the previous `similar users` scores of around ~40 aren't great results.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "good", or "bad" scores, they are not interpretable. Those scores are used *only* for sorting the recommendations, where the higher score means the more recommended the product is in given setting.

As you can read in the [*Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets* paper by Hu et al](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf), the algorithm minimizes

$$
\min_{x,y} \sum_{u,i} c_{ui} (p_{ui} - x_u^T y_i)^2 + \lambda\Big(\sum_u\|x_u\|^2 + \sum_i\|y_i\|^2\Big)
$$

where $c_{ui}$ is the weight described in the paper, $x_u$ is latent vector representing user, and $y_i$ is latent vector representing item. The dot product $x_u^T y_i$ needs to be as close as possible to binary indicator of preference $p_{ui}$, so closer it is to one, the more recommended the item is to the user, and the closer to zero, the less recommended. As you can notice, there is no hard bounds, so it can take any possible value. By finding the optimal parameters we would push those values arbitrary close to zero or one, but by introducing the weights and regularization, additional factors may push them in different directions.